# How to import postgresql file on Linux with space in path?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, postgresql, sql, import

If I try to import an sql script with a space in path, the file is not found.

```
mypsqluser=> \i /home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My App/Installation/server_sql_script.sql
/home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My: No such file or directory
```

I tried to escape it, with backslash, double backslash or quotes, but it doesn't work either, see:

```
mypsqluser=> \i /home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My\ App/Installation/server_sql_script.sql
/home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My: No such file or directory

mypsqluser=> \i "/home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My App/Installation/server_sql_script.sql"
"/home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My App/Installation/server_sql_script.sql": No such file or directory
```

It only works if there are no spaces in path. But how is it to do with spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes will do it; escaping the space then is optional:
\i '/home/markus/Documents/Projekte/My\ App/Installation/server_sql_script.sql'

Comment: embarrassing, didn't notice that :)